# Small Form-factor Pluggable(SFP): basic , connection with 2.SFP

Tags: sfp, optics, optical

**My understanding of SFP functionality. **

SFP is an “interface” between 2 parts of a device.

SFP is a transceiver There are input and output, electrical to optical or optical to electrical. SFP includes a laser diode and photodiode.

Optical fibre connects 2 SFP module via LC connector.

If output signal of SFP is electrical, how can it be connected via optical fibre?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

An SFP module isn't a complete interface - it's just the last part of a physical-layer interface, forming the *Physical Medium Dependent* (PMD) sublayer between the *Physical Medium Attachment* (PMA) and the medium.

> If output signal of SFP is electrical, how can it be connected via optical fibre?

As you've stated, a transceiver consists of a transmitter (e.g. a laser) and a receiver (e.g. a photodiode) for the used medium. For optical media, those components convert the electrical signal from the SFP socket to an optical one and vice versa.

Of course, transceivers also exist for twisted-pair copper cable which may or may not require active transcoding inside the SFP module (e.g. from 1000BASE-X to 1000BASE-T) and the ubiquitous direct-attach cables (DAC) with affixed twinax cabling.

Comment: I am trying to understand if SFP is used in optical satellite terminals. [1](https://www.tesat.de/products), [2](https://mynaric.com/products/space/condor-mk2/). These terminals have optical fibre inside I am sure. They transmit optical signal. A transmit device/telescope should be connected with other parts via optical fibre.

Comment: Theoretically possible but very unlikely, given that SFPs are intended for low(er)-power, fiber-based optical and that satellite tech needs to be highly optimized (power, weight, radiation hardening, longevity).

Comment: What can be used to connect electrical and optical parts?

Comment: Sorry, this site is about *about professionally managed networks in a business environment*, see the [help] - for engineering satellites [space.se] might be more appropriate.

Comment: @NoelMiller, there are also SFPs that are not optical. We often use 10/100/1000Base-T SFPs, and even 10GBase-T SFP+s when devices are in the same closet, only using optical for distant devices.

Comment: I have noticed the receiver sensitivity of current SPF max -25 dBm, Is it possible to have more?

Comment: The sensitivity of an SFP modules depends on the Ethernet variant it uses (and higher baud rates cause lower sensitivity). 1000BASE-LX10 requires -19.5 dBm, 10GBASE-LR -12.6 dBm, 10GBASE-ER -14.1 dBm and so on. -25 dBm seems to be the max for 10G, 1G modules go up to -33 dBm.